# Syntax error in batch file

Tags: batch-file

The code below is returning the following error:

> ```
> The syntax of the command is incorrect."
> ```

But I have no clue which line is causing this.

```
@echo off
for /D %%d in (*) do (
    cd %%d
    for %%f in (*_c.lua) do (
        set FROM=%%f
        set TO=%FROM%"c"
        C:\curl.exe -s -X POST -F compile=1 -F debug=0 -F obfuscate=2 -F luasource=@%FROM% http://luac.mtasa.com/ > %TO%
    )
    cd ..
)
pause
```

Comment: Do not run the batch file by double-clicking on its icon; instead, open a command prompt window, manoeuvre to the path of the script ([`cd /D`](http://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) and run the batch file by typing its name. Then remove the `@echo off` command temporarily. So your can debug the batch file as you can see what is actually going on. One thing in advance: you are missing [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)...

Comment: Well if you turn echo on you will probably see the problem. Regardless of that, you also have a problem with your FROM and TO variables.  You have to reference them using Delayed Expansion.  But in reality, I see no reason why you can't just use the FOR variable directly in your CURL execution.

Comment: In fact, the problem with the TO variable is the cause of the syntax error issue. Because the TO variable isn't set to anything, there is nothing after the > redirection, and that causes the syntax error

Comment: @Richard nope. Read again `set TO=%FROM%"c"`. Unusual however valid. Squashman's comment is closer.

Comment: What should `TO` look like?  `test_c.lua"c"`?

Comment: @JosefZ Try it yourself. The issue is that %TO% in the curl.exe command line is expanded before the FOR loop is executed, at which time it is not defined. It's necessary to set enabledelayedexpansion and use !FROM!

Answer (score 0):

Add `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` at the top, then change any variable references within the loop to use `!` instead of `%`.  [See more info here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php).

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /D %%d in (*) do (
    cd %%d
    for %%f in (*_c.lua) do (
        set FROM=%%f
        set TO=!FROM!"c"
        echo "C:\curl.exe -s -X POST -F compile=1 -F debug=0 -F obfuscate=2 -F luasource=@!FROM! http://luac.mtasa.com/ > !TO!"
        C:\curl.exe -s -X POST -F compile=1 -F debug=0 -F obfuscate=2 -F luasource=@!FROM! http://luac.mtasa.com/ > !TO!
    )
    cd ..
)
```

Comment: You forgot to change `set TO=%FROM%"c"` to `set TO=!FROM!"c"` Even better it would be to omit the additional set commands and use `%%f` directly.

Comment: Putting the `curl.exe` command line cannot work, because the entire line is considered as a path/file to be executed then...

Comment: Updated answer to fix the things addressed above, except removing the extraneous variables.